# TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, openweathermap

I'm trying to fetch data from API and use that data in my app. But the problem is when I try to get certain object or data from the JSON I've just got from API, I get:

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of undefined**.

The property **DO** exist.
By the way, I'm using React.js. 
I really appreciate your help and guidance.
Here is the code:

App.js

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation/Navigation";
import Forecast from "./components/forecast/forecast";
// function

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            responseFromAPI: {},
        }
    }

    getPosition = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
        });
    }
    getWeather = async function (latitude, longtitude) {
        const One_weather_call = await fetch(`https://community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longtitude}&units=metric`,
            {
                "method": "GET",
                "headers": {
                    "x-rapidapi-host": "some private info here",
                    "x-rapidapi-key": "some private info here"
                }
            }).then(response => response.json());

        console.log("fetch data");
        return One_weather_call;

    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getPosition()
            .then(position => {
                this.getWeather(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
                    .then(res => {this.setState({responseFromAPI: res});
                    });
            });

        console.log("after setting response in app.js ", this.state.responseFromAPI);


    };

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Navigation city={this.state.responseFromAPI.name}

                            country={this.state.responseFromAPI.sys.country}
                />

            </React.Fragment>
        );
    };
}

export default App;
```

JSON

```json
{"coord": { "lon": 139,"lat": 35},
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01n"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 281.52,
    "feels_like": 278.99,
    "temp_min": 280.15,
    "temp_max": 283.71,
    "pressure": 1016,
    "humidity": 93
  },
  "wind": {
    "speed": 0.47,
    "deg": 107.538
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 2
  },
  "dt": 1560350192,
  "sys": {
    "type": 3,
    "id": 2019346,
    "message": 0.0065,
    "country": "JP",
    "sunrise": 1560281377,
    "sunset": 1560333478
  },
  "timezone": 32400,
  "id": 1851632,
  "name": "Shuzenji",
  "cod": 200
}
```

As you can see, country in this JSON data is placed like
`json.sys.country` but I get error this way. But there is no error when I try to access other variables like `json.main`.

Comment: The data doesn't exist until the Ajax request is completed. You need to have `this.state = { responseFromAPI: null }` in the constructor and put `if(!this.state.responseFromAPI) { return <div>Loading...</div>; }` or something similar to the render function.

Comment: Alternatively you can use optional chaining on the state properties being accessed, i.e. `this.state.responseFromAPI?.sys?.country`, but be aware this potentially passes `undefined` to the child component so it would also need to be able to handle it.

Comment: @GuyIncognito ajax completes, there is no problem with JSON data being set to the `responseFromAPI`, the problem is, I can't get only the specified data which is country in this case.
only problem is country, i can get rest of the data. 
country itself is available in the json.

Comment: It is because `this.state.responseFromAPI` is initially a defined object, so during the initial render before the data is fetched accessing `this.state.responseFromAPI.name` is ok and returns `undefined`, same as if you accessed `this.state.responseFromAPI.sys`, it returns undefined, but when you try to access `country` of `this.state.responseFromAPI.sys` you are accessing a property of an undefined object and that will throw error.

Comment: Again, the problem is that the render function runs before the Ajax has completed.

Comment: @GuyIncognito  *"the problem is that the render function runs before the Ajax has completed."* this part got me and I finally fixed it. thanks for the guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to fix issue by conditionally setting the props for components in `render()` function like this:

```js
  render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>

                <Navigation city={this.state.responseFromAPI ? this.state.responseFromAPI.name : ""}

                            country={this.state.responseFromAPI ? this.state.responseFromAPI.sys.country
                            : "Loading"}
                />

            </React.Fragment>
        );
    };
```